# Append function seems doesn't works in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need an array of JSON files to insert in a DB because bulk_doc (array_of_json) is more efficient and faster than Createdoc (json_doc)
I wrote this code:

```
    with open('C:\DATA_VOTES_CST_PTY.csv', 'r') as f:
       key = f.readline().replace('\n', '').replace('\"', '').split(',')
       while (True) :
           line = f.readline()
           if (line == '') :
               break
           else :
               value = line.replace('\n', '').replace('\"', '').split(',')
           for i in range(len(key)):
               app.update({key[i] : value[i]})
           json_doc = json.dumps(app)
           print(json_doc) #print what I want
                  docs.append(json_doc)
       print("\n", json_doc)
print("now print docs: ")
print(docs) #print nothing, neither errors
```

The doc contains one 1Milion of lines. I don't know what to do about this problem, it seems like append dosen't work.

PS: I'm using Python 3.8 on Spyder4 Anaconda

------EDIT------
[image: the output]

Comment: where you have defined `docs`

Comment: append is working fine, you need to look at how you're reading the file, your .readline usage is confused

Comment: Does `print(json_doc)` output what you expect? And is the 2nd line of your CSV a blank line?

Comment: @shivank98 docs is defined as docs = [] on the top (I haven't pasted this line of code)

Comment: @aneroid print(json_doc) is exactly the json I've made.

Comment: @User632716 if I print key and value and `json_doc' and I have what I expect, I think that are working good and isn't correlated to my problem

Comment: @Malotino can you try to show a little bit of output also? It will help in debugging.

Comment: @shivank98 I edited the question

Comment: You can use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from the standard library to avoid all the replacing and splitting.

Comment: Anyway, the first comment should be addressed: where is the `docs` variable defined?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm new on python and I wasn't aware of existence of csv module, about `docs = []` it's defined on the top and i haven't pasted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this csv:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

this code

```
import csv
import json

docs = []

with open('test.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        docs.append(json.dumps(row))

print(docs)
```

generates this output

```
['{"A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "3"}', '{"A": "4", "B": "5", "C": "6"}', '{"A": "7", "B": "8", "C": "9"}']
```

If you want a JSON array rather than a list of JSON objects, you can do

```
docs = list(reader)
json_array = json.dumps(docs)
```

Comment: I don't get the reason for not printing anything in `print(docs)` in question. I get that docs has strings in it. but why it doesn't print that.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer to that question is in code that you haven't shared in the question.  I'd guess that the `docs` that gets printed and the `docs` that is being appended to are two different objects.

Comment: I didn't ask the question. though I am still not sure, how there can be different objects of docs. quite interesting.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't check the username.  One possibility: `docs` is declared at module-level, the file-reading code is in a function where a local `docs` is defined.  Note that `print(docs)` in the OP's screenshot does _not_ output `[]`.

Comment: I also tried this code and it doesn't print, but in both codes it works with a document that has about 13 thousand lines. So I think the problem is given by the number of lines that exceed one million

Comment: If you have million lines then maybe just print `len(docs)`.  This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400077/does-the-print-function-in-python-have-a-limit-of-string-length-it-can-print